# Python regex string to list of words (including words with hyphens)

Tags: python, regex

I would like to parse a string to obtain a list including all words (hyphenated words, too). Current code is:

```
s = '-this is. A - sentence;one-word'
re.compile("\W+",re.UNICODE).split(s)
```

returns:

```
['', 'this', 'is', 'A', 'sentence', 'one', 'word']
```

and I would like it to return:

```
['', 'this', 'is', 'A', 'sentence', 'one-word']
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need the leading empty string, you could use the pattern `\w(?:[-\w]*\w)?` for *matching*:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '-this is. A - sentence;one-word'
>>> rx = re.compile(r'\w(?:[-\w]*\w)?')
>>> rx.findall(s)
['this', 'is', 'A', 'sentence', 'one-word']
```

Note that it won't match words with apostrophes like `won't`.

Answer (score 2):

Here my traditional "why to use regexp language when you can use Python" alternative:

```
import string
s = "-this is. A - sentence;one-word what's"
s = filter(None,[word.strip(string.punctuation)
                 for word in s.replace(';','; ').split()
                 ])
print s
""" Output:
['this', 'is', 'A', 'sentence', 'one-word', "what's"]
"""
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `"[^\w-]+"` instead.

Comment: That would return `-this` but I know no better solution either. I feel there is no way without going over the result once more to remove the unwanted minuses.

Answer (score 1):

`s = "-this is. A - sentence;one-word what's"

re.findall("\w+-\w+|[\w']+",s)`

result:
['this', 'is', 'A', 'sentence', 'one-word', "what's"]

make sure you notice that the correct ordering is to look for hyypenated words first!

Answer (score 0):

Yo can try with the NLTK library:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> s = '-this is a - sentence;one-word'
>>> hyphen = r'(\w+\-\s?\w+)'
>>> wordr = r'(\w+)'
>>> r = "|".join([ hyphen, wordr])
>>> tokens = nltk.tokenize.regexp_tokenize(s,r)
>>> print tokens
['this', 'is', 'a', 'sentence', 'one-word']
```

I found it here: http://www.cs.oberlin.edu/~jdonalds/333/lecture03.html Hope it helps